# How can I decide the orders of auto-loading fixture into test database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

I got very complicated data structure that require fixture data been loaded into database by some specific order, but I can't figure out ways to do it.

Comment: Fixture data should just be the contents of the table. Why does it matter which order the tables are populated in?

Comment: For example, tweets were added with user_id (foreign key), but user table don't have any data at all. This populating would cause errors, wouldn't this?

Comment: It shouldn't do, as long as the user table is populated at some point before the test is ran. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails), a fixture replacement. Instead of manually creating data to load per table, factory_girl uses your models and associations to create test data. An example factory from the [wiki](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Usage):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name 'John'
    last_name  'Doe'
    age        { 1 + rand(100) }
  end

  factory :admin, :parent => :user do
    admin true
  end
end
```

Then after configuring your tests to use factory_girl, you can simply use the following to create models:

```
# Saved instance
user = create(:user)

# Unsaved instance
user = build(:user)
```

If you need to create large amounts of data that is reused for multiple tests, you can wrap all the factory_girl calls into a method in the test_helper that can be access by multiple tests.